# Show the sequence: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0

Tags: python

I am practicing python. I cannot solve this exercise.
Implement a program that shows the following sequence:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0

For a bigger challenge: Use a single while, a single if and a single else

```
x = 0
while x < 5:
    x = x + 1
    print(x)
    if x == 5:
        x =  x - 1
        print(x)
```

this is what i have at this moment. but is doesnt work

Comment: In the same way that you are looping from 1 to 5, you'll need to loop from 5 down to 0, but you can't only do that for the value 5.

Comment: `print(', '.join(str(x) for x in list(range(1,6)) + list(range(4,-1,-1))))`?

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 0
isRising = True
while x > 0 or isRising:
    if isRising and x < 5:
        x += 1
    else:
        isRising = False
        x -= 1
    print (x)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing some additional context regarding how and why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways this could be handled; but based on your code, is that what you are after?

```
count = 0
direction = 1

while True:
    count+= direction
    print(count)
    if count == 5:
        direction = -1
    elif count == 0:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 variables to do that.

```
x = 1
a = 1
while x > 0:
    print(x),
    x = x + a
    if x == 5:
        a = -1

print(x)
```

```
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
>>> m = 1
>>> i = 1
>>> while i >= 0:
    print(i)
    if i == 5:
        m = -1
    i += m


1
2
3
4
5
4
3
2
1
0
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here it is.

```
print("Sequence:")
x=1
y=1
while x>=0:
 if x>=1 and x<=4:
  print(x)
  x+=y
 else:
  y=-1
  print(x)
  x+=y
```